# php Adding seconds from a variable

Tags: php

Im trying to add seconds to a result from a variable

So what happens is:

for example:

```php
$eta = "14:12:00";   // this is an example from another result
```

then i have

```php
$newseconds = "6" //where 6 is the seconds which randomly change
```

Now what i want to get working is that the newseconds whill be added to the eta

so that the end result will be 14:12:06

How can i do this?

I now  have something like

```php
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime('+12 seconds',strtotime($eta))).PHP_EOL
```

but the +12 seconds should then be coming from newseconds...

Thank you for the help

Comment: use timestamps ??..

Comment: @Vidal timestamps are only machine-readable, often is more useful using human-readable date-time formats.

Comment: all solutions are using timestapms... strtotime returns a timestamp then they add the desired value and use date to format the timestamp to their desired format. ("H:i:s")

Comment: @Vidal yep, but the difference I'm talking about is the value that all of us can read in the code/Web: the human-readable format.

Answer (score 4):

You can add seconds like this:

```
echo $newTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime("$eta + $newseconds seconds"));
```

output:

```
14:12:06
```

Try it [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7307992f0f0b20e150160df7ca224f43b9c7f0e1).

As you see, you can enclose the whole calculation between `" "`, so it's more readable.

Also, you need to call `strtotime` once, which makes the script faster.

You can learn more about `strtotime` in the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/strtotime).

Answer (score 2):

Just concat `$newseconds` to the added time string:

```
$eta = "14:12:00";
$newseconds = "6";
echo date('H:i:s',strtotime(+$newseconds.' seconds',strtotime($eta)));
```

Result `14:12:06` [example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40c0808fb19486ed685fb39ec819fa2af182cfa5)

Comment: "+" should be in quotes, shouldn't it?

Comment: It doesn't have to be @droopsnoot http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/40c0808fb19486ed685fb39ec819fa2af182cfa5

Comment: Ah, learn something new every day. So glad I phrased it that way.

Comment: Looks like you can remove the `+` as well(but will be less readable for humans).

Comment: Nice find @vivek_23!

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect now

Answer (score 0):

Why not using PHP 's own `DateTime` class?

```
$seconds = 6;
$time = '14:12:00';

echo DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time)
    ->modify('+' . $seconds . 'seconds')
    ->format('H:i:s');
```

Using the `DateTime` class enabled method chaining and you can use all methods this object includes. Read more in the documentation under [PHP: DateTime - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).